# GitHub Clone URL in Windows without using GitHub's Windows official client

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I'm just learning about Git and GitHub stuff, so I'm reading a tutorial where in a step it says I need to get in the GitHub's website my "Clone URL" and "Public Clone URL".

The tutorial is not particularly recent, so at present if I go to GitHub's website, I see a "Clone in Windows" button which forces me to install "GitHub for Windows" official client.

Even if this works, I come from a Linux environment and in my present work I need to use Windows (want it or not). I've already installed and configured Cygwin, Console2 and Msysgit to work with Git Bash in conjunction with these software to be able to use a console, so I find frustrating be forced to use a Windows client when all I want is this Clone URL stuff...

So, my question is, how do I get this URL without installing this Windows client? Is there a way? Am I misunderstanding something? I'm just trying to learn Git and GitHub so I can do my work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL should be right next to the "Clone in Windows" button.

The various options such as "HTTPS" and "Git Read-Only" correspond to the newer versions of "Clone URL" and "Public Clone URL".

Comment: Is that so... Well I'm learning after all! So I really don't need that Windows client to work with GIT and GitHub, do I? =P

Comment: No, it's just another UI for git. According to [this blog post](https://github.com/blog/1127-github-for-windows) it even uses msysGit.